# Helper function in jQuery - draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to write a `helper` function for jQueryUI to set an attribute on an item being dragged from a 'draggable' list to a 'sortable' list.  (The reason I need to do this is that the latest version of jQueryUI deletes the 'id' attribute of dropped items)

However the attribute is not making it to the 'sortable' list.  Am I doing something wrong in the helper function?

```
$("#draggable > li").draggable({
  connectToSortable: "#sortable",
  helper: function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var ret = $(this).clone();
    ret.attr('dragId', id);
    console.log('dragId: ', ret.attr('dragId'));
    return ret();
  }
});

$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    start: function( event, ui ) {
          console.log( "sortable start: dragId=", ui.item.attr( "dragId" ) );
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
          console.log( "sortable stop: dragId=", ui.item.attr( "dragId" ) );
    }
});
```

When I drag an item from the draggable list to the sortable list, it prints in the console:

```
dragId: itemA
sortable start: dragId= undefined
sortable stop: dragId= undefined
```

I would expect it to print:

```
dragId: itemA
sortable start: dragId= itemA
sortable stop: dragId= itemA
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/owuxek/9/edit) is the full example (with HTML) on JsBin

Comment: If it's true that "the latest version of jQueryUI deletes the 'id' attribute of dropped items", then save the id off and re-apply it in the drop event handler of your droppable (you'll need to add a droppable).

Comment: Global variable, a child of the li, any number of places.

Comment: Note:  the code is slightly different in the JsBin example.  the last line of the helper function here has () after it, which should not be there.  You want to return the ret object, not execute it and return the result.

Comment: The jsbin example generates an error and doesn't work.  ($ not defined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the `dragId` attribute on the *helper* element, so you should use `ui.helper` instead of `ui.item`:

```
console.log("sortable start: dragId=", ui.helper.attr("dragId"));
```

**EDIT:** Nicola Peluchetti is right in his comment below: `ui.helper` will indeed be `null` during the `stop` event. Since you probably want to use the `dragId` attribute during that event, a workaround would be to copy the attribute during the `start` event, when both `ui.helper` and `ui.item` are available:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
          ui.item.attr("dragId", ui.helper.attr("dragId"));
          console.log("sortable start: dragId=", ui.item.attr("dragId"));
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
          console.log("sortable stop: dragId=", ui.item.attr("dragId"));
    }
});
```

Comment: That's true only for the start function (not the stop one)

Comment: @Nicola, you mean the helper does not have a `dragId` attribute during the `stop` event?

Comment: No i checked it with firebug and actually ui.helper is null in the stop function

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep the id i found is adding a droppable and this code:

```
    $( "#sortable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(ui.draggable).attr('id', $(ui.helper).attr('id'));
        }
    });
```

There is a fiddle here (and there must be a better way of doing this) http://jsfiddle.net/MdZwB/1/